# How can I delete a paused application download on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I started installing an application from the App Store but forgot to check its size. When I check now, it is 50 MB. Now I don't want to download that application any more because I'm on 3G plan which is costly. I paused it but don't know how to delete it. Can anyone help me on how to delete a paused app download?

Comment: I think it goes away when you reboot the iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't delete the paused download (which, I'm thinking, suggests you aren't on the most recent release of iOS), then the simplest option that doesn't require a restore is going to be to find a WiFi hotspot and let the app finish downloading. Personally, I'd go that route (especially if out-and-about or on vacation, etc.) before wiping my data and having to restore again.

Alternatively, leave it on paused until you get home to your primary network. Your phone doesn't care two cents about your paused app downloads, so it shouldn't get in the way of anything.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that paused downloads get removed by rebooting in iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully deleted them like any other app: press and hold on the icon until all of the icons start shaking, tap the X in the red circle on the icon and confirm the deletion, then press the hardware Home button to end deletion mode.

I will say that these have all been apps that failed to complete downloading, nothing that I've intentionally paused, but I'd think it would be the same.

Comment: there is no X icon for paused download.

Comment: @Jitendra Hmm. If the simple reboot suggested by bckbck doesn't work then the more drastic option -- which should definitely work -- is to back up your phone (via iTunes), erase the content (via the iPhone Settings App, under General • Reset • Erase All Content and Settings), and then restore it (via iTunes).

Answer (score -2):

1. Download and open [iTools](http://www.itools.cn/en_index.htm).
2. Click Filesystem.
3. Go to the downloads folder.
4. Delete everything.
5. Reboot iPhone.
   After reboot, don't enter your Apple ID.

Comment: Be aware: [reviews on CNET](http://download.cnet.com/iTools/3000-2248_4-75629761.html#rateit) claim this software installs adware/malware.

Comment: Seems like a dubious recommendation.

Answer (score -2):

Slide left on download and delete.

Comment: Could you expand on *where* the user should 'slide left'?